# Why is the CSS not linking to my html?

Tags: html, css

I generally use Notepad++ in Windows to write HTML and CSS (I am a beginner). However, I also like using Linux a lot and work in Ubuntu a lot. I use BlueFish editor in Ubuntu.

My problem is that in BlueFish when I put in simple CSS styles and link them to the HTML document and go into a browser to preview, there is nothing there besides the HTML that was written (paragraphs, text, images etc..)

This is what I have for HTML: I just need to know if I'm linking correctly and if so, when I create a "style.css" document why it doesn't function properly.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!-- This is a mockup page -->
<html>
    <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
        <title>Daily News</title>

    </head>

    <body>

    <ul id="nav

        <li><a href="#" >Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" >About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" >Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" >Contact</a></li>

    </ul>

    <div id="p1">
    <h4>Coding is fun</h4>
<p>Morbi posuere fermentum urna non iaculis. Vivamus posuere felis sed orci luctus vel tempor nunc ultrices. Sed accumsan mauris ac orci condimentum id posuere tellus tincidunt. Aliquam pellentesque tortor ac magna porttitor luctus. Fusce nec augue in est tempus mollis ac ut libero. Vestibulum eget mi eu orci vestibulum ullamcorper sed non ligula. Nulla facilisi. Sed consectetur, libero imperdiet condimentum mattis, nisl tortor fringilla tortor, in consequat erat libero eget diam. Ut tortor erat, tincidunt vel cursus ut, varius sit amet est. </p>
    <h4>Open Source is for the better good</h4>
<p>Morbi posuere fermentum urna non iaculis. Vivamus posuere felis sed orci luctus vel tempor nunc ultrices. Sed accumsan mauris ac orci condimentum id posuere tellus tincidunt. Aliquam pellentesque tortor ac magna porttitor luctus. Fusce nec augue in est tempus mollis ac ut libero. Vestibulum eget mi eu orci vestibulum ullamcorper sed non ligula. Nulla facilisi. Sed consectetur, libero imperdiet condimentum mattis, nisl tortor fringilla tortor, in consequat erat libero eget diam. Ut tortor erat, tincidunt vel cursus ut, varius sit amet est. </p>
    <h4>Ubuntu 12.10 is coming out next week</h4>
<p>Aenean commodo libero at purus varius at bibendum lacus gravida. Nullam sollicitudin, justo eget hendrerit pharetra, massa est ullamcorper sem, vitae commodo nulla risus eget tortor. Curabitur viverra hendrerit ornare. Donec eu nisl erat. Suspendisse sed bibendum metus. Praesent luctus euismod odio ut semper. Suspendisse molestie vulputate sapien eleifend hendrerit. Nullam gravida cursus mattis. </p>

<div id="right_sidebar"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">

<footer>Webpage designed by me</footer>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

****Also I started learning from Codeyear.com any other good resources out on the net for learning HTML CSS Javascript?***

THANK YOU

Comment: ocw.mit.edu is another good resource for beginning coders.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I cleaned up your HTML a bit. Remember that your indentation should be consistent - your close tags should align with your open tags, etc.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!-- This is a mockup page -->
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
        <title>Daily News</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <ul id="nav>
            <li><a href="#" >Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" >About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" >Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" >Contact</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div id="p1">
            <h4>Coding is fun</h4>
            <p>Morbi posuere fermentum urna non iaculis. Vivamus posuere felis sed orci luctus vel tempor nunc ultrices. Sed accumsan mauris ac orci condimentum id posuere tellus tincidunt. Aliquam pellentesque tortor ac magna porttitor luctus. Fusce nec augue in est tempus mollis ac ut libero. Vestibulum eget mi eu orci vestibulum ullamcorper sed non ligula. Nulla facilisi. Sed consectetur, libero imperdiet condimentum mattis, nisl tortor fringilla tortor, in consequat erat libero eget diam. Ut tortor erat, tincidunt vel cursus ut, varius sit amet est. </p>

            <h4>Open Source is for the better good</h4>
            <p>Morbi posuere fermentum urna non iaculis. Vivamus posuere felis sed orci luctus vel tempor nunc ultrices. Sed accumsan mauris ac orci condimentum id posuere tellus tincidunt. Aliquam pellentesque tortor ac magna porttitor luctus. Fusce nec augue in est tempus mollis ac ut libero. Vestibulum eget mi eu orci vestibulum ullamcorper sed non ligula. Nulla facilisi. Sed consectetur, libero imperdiet condimentum mattis, nisl tortor fringilla tortor, in consequat erat libero eget diam. Ut tortor erat, tincidunt vel cursus ut, varius sit amet est. </p>

            <h4>Ubuntu 12.10 is coming out next week</h4>
            <p>Aenean commodo libero at purus varius at bibendum lacus gravida. Nullam sollicitudin, justo eget hendrerit pharetra, massa est ullamcorper sem, vitae commodo nulla risus eget tortor. Curabitur viverra hendrerit ornare. Donec eu nisl erat. Suspendisse sed bibendum metus. Praesent luctus euismod odio ut semper. Suspendisse molestie vulputate sapien eleifend hendrerit. Nullam gravida cursus mattis. </p>

            <div id="right_sidebar"></div>
        </div>

        <div id="footer">
            <footer>Webpage designed by me</footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As to why your CSS may not be showing up - remember that the CSS file must be correctly placed relative to the HTML page that is linking to it. This is a mock directory structure, for example, based on your `<link>` tag in the above code:

```
/
/style.css
/index.html
```

Now, if the style.css were in its own folder, it should be as follows:

```
/
/css/styles.css
/index.html
```

And in the latter case, the link tag would read `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" />`

I don't quite see how Bluefish would be interfering with the CSS file not being loaded. If you're using Chrome or IE, press `F12` to bring up the developer console with the Network tab open and then reload the page and see that the style.css is being loaded correctly (should return a 200 OK or 300 Not Modified code if I recall correctly). You can perform the same operation in Firefox with Firebug.

Comment: Got ya! I solved the problem about an hour ago. I realized that I was typing in Generic HTML (default), so I switched over to HTML5 and then viewed in browser again and it works. My main problem is that I have issues with positioning things in css, I have not understood that yet. Thank you for the help though.

Comment: You'll get there...dealing with cross-browser positioning and other issues is a pain.

Answer (score 0):

Your style.css file needs to be in the same directory on the web server as your html file.

Comment: I put both files in a folder on the desktop named "webpage" but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's solve the problem or not but you should finish the `ul` tag. Change

```
<ul id="nav
```

to

```
<ul id="nav">
```

Comment: No, I just tried that. But thank though. I am just so bumped because BlueFish is such a good editor in my opinion and I'm really hoping that it isn't the editor but me. So that's why I'm confused as to what is wrong...